# How to compute distances along a network in shapefile? in R

Tags: r, networking, gis, distance, shapefile

I have a river network in a shapefile (class: "SpatialLinesDataFrame"), with some points on it (see picture below).

I would like to compute the distances between points, but along the rivers. I have been searching a lot and I am not able to find any function that allows directly that.

The closest thing I have found is the function "networkdistance" in the package "secrlinear", however I don't manage to transform my shapefile into the format required to use the function (a "linearmask" object).

Any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tina.

[image]

Comment: Assuming you can identify each point uniquely, you could calculate a cumulative sum of distances from point to point to point along a river.  You would need to "group" rivers (i.e. points), such as the four in the most point-filled river.  And the result would be approximate, but there are several packages that calculate land miles (or kilometers) between points.

Comment: Maybe routing may help: http://rpubs.com/geospacedman/routing

Comment: Thanks! to do it as @lawyeR proposes I would need to somehow extract the portion of river between two given points. Once I have that it would be easier to get the cumulative sum between the points that form the river's shapefile. The problem is that I have to confess that I don't know how to isolate the portion of river between 2 points...

Comment: Thanks @Edi, but apparently I'm not able to convert my shapefile to igraph class either...

Comment: But if you can locate the points on the river network, which you must have done to plot them as red dots, you can add a column to group them by river and order along the river, right?

Comment: thanks @lawyer, but all of them are in the same river, so distances can be computed among all of them. I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Why don't you post your data and code?  Or at least a sample of it that created the plot you put in your question.

Comment: you are right, I'll create a new post about this issue with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we resolved this problem offline: the geographic coordinates (lat/long) of the shapefile needed to be projected before they could be used in secrlinear. That package approximates the linear network and uses igraph functions for distances.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case someone runs across this in the future: I just released an R package (riverdist) that deals with this issue, and also provides some tools for network editing and data summaries & visualization.  It was written with fisheries work in mind, but could probably be applied to what you're working on, or at least that's the hope!

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverdist/vignettes/riverdist_vignette.html

Sorry this wasn't more timely -

Comment: Amazing Matt! Thank you very much for this. My problem is to calculate distances from 2 points on a map, on a bus route shapefile. Can your functions be extrapolated  to my problem? Cheers!